# Unable to get information from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a web app on MEAN stack. MongoDB Atlas is set with Database, Collections and data. I am receiving an empty array. There should be 12 row data. Username, password and DB Name are correct. And the console does not show any error. Below is my code, but I cannot find the issue. What am I doing wrong?

mongoose.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.5zol8.mongodb.net/<DB Name>?retryWrites=true&w=majority', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => console.log('Database connected'))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));

module.exports = mongoose;
```

confession.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ConfessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    feelings: {
        type: [String],
        minlength: 1
    }, 
    confession: {
        type: String
    },
    isApproved: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    }
});

const Confession = mongoose.model('Confessions', ConfessionSchema);

module.exports = Confession;
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

const mongoose = require('./database/mongoose');

const Confession = require('./database/confession');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3100;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  next();
});

app.get('/getConfessions', (req, res) => {
    Confession.find({})
        .then(confession => {console.log("Hello" + confession.toString()); res.send(confession);})
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Server running on port 3100'));
```

Comment: I assume `<username>` `<password>` and `<DB Name>` are correctly set? You also want to be using `res.json(confession)` to convert the confessions to JSON. Otherwise I don't see an immediate error

Comment: Are you sure there are 12 records in your DB, cause I do not find anything wrong with the code, What about the name of the collection.

Comment: The names are right and yes there are 12 records

Comment: Code seems right to me as well. Are you sure you're connecting to the right DB?

Comment: Yes because I can see stats in MongoDB Atlas. Database is getting accessed. The collection (table) name also does not have any error.